# Is there any way to use google-swiffy on a file larger than 1mb

Tags: google-swiffy

I was going to try google-swiffy, but the .swf file I have is 1.9 MB in size, so the service rejects it. I am looking for a work around or an alternative. My swf is an interactive slide show.

Comment: Install the Swiffy extension in Adobe Extension Manager and then export to HTML5 in Flash instead of using the online converter.

Comment: @APAD1 the extension appears to have a 1024kb limit too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [swiffy-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiffy-convert) and batch-convert all those.

Comment: @APAD1 it returns a 413 error (too large). i think it all uses their web service and is subject to the size restriction.